# codeigniter 3 .htaccess file is not working

Tags: codeigniter-3, .htaccess

im using codeigniter 3.1.9 and XAMP. i try eevrything but is not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Elaborate more on what's not working.

Comment: I'm try to remove index.php from url

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foldername/
# RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note : If you put ".htaccess" inside a folder, don't forget to add RewriteBase.